Why not just give up on the idea of truth-functionality?
I understand that today only a minority of academics who are specialised in formal logic accept the horseshoe (aka "Classical Logic" or "First-Order Logic") as an accurate, or even a good model, of the implication (or conditional).
On the other hand, one argument seems to be that there is no alternative if we are to preserve the idea that the implication (or conditional) is truth-functional.
I understand how truth-functionality may look like a desirable property for a formal treatment of the implication (or conditional), but it is apparently an obstacle to progress.
So, why cannot we just drop the idea that the implication (or conditional) is truth-functional?
Thank you for any scholarly references.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Related to your question: "At what point in the history of mathematics, and why, did mathematicians come to say 'A implies B' to mean 'not A or B'?"
